# jsp filter, get page name

Tags: java, security, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to create a jsp login filter.

The filter should:

- intercept requests to any page; verify whether the request is part of a logged-session
- if the session is not logged, redirect the client to a login page
- if the requested page is the login page, don't redirect, otherwise it will loop

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter's implementation scheme is outlined (no code; I'm assuming that you know that Servlet API, which is a prerequisite).

> intercept requests to any page; verify whether the request is part of a logged-session

You ought to be creating the servlet filter, and map it against `/*`, so that all requests to the application will be intercepted by this filter. Tracking of authenticated users is assumed to be done using a Session attribute. You can extract the session from the `HttpServletRequest` object within the filter, and extract the attribute using the `getAttribute()` method.

> if the session is not logged, redirect the client to a login page

If the session or the attribute does not exist, or the attribute is false, then you'll need to redirect the user to the login page, using the `sendRedirect()` method on the HttpServletResponse object.

> if the requested page is the login page, don't redirect, otherwise it will loop

You can determine whether the request is to the login page using the getServletPath() method on the HttpServletRequest object. But this is unnecessary if you do the following:

- put the login page and other "public" content in the document root directory, i.e. in the `/ApplicationContext/` directory*.
- put the protected content (including all servlet mappings) in the `/ApplicationContext/protected` directory.
- Map the filter only to `/protected` instead of `/*`. The filter will therefore intercept requests only to protected resources. Be careful when you map any resource to a different path.

* The ApplicationContext is your application's context path. If your web site is at `http://example.com/App` then the context is usually `App`. Your login page should therefore be `http://example.com/App/login.jsp`, while a protected page would be accessed as `http://example.com/App/protected/secret.jsp`

Comment: thanks for the precise answer. 1) why don't use request.getUserPrincipal() instead of "manually" storing data in an attribute? 2) getServletPath() will fail in the case of "welcome files" (maybe other jsf cases...?). It will return the directory, not the servlet name

Comment: request.getUserPrincipal() and request.getRemoteUser() will work for container manager authentication. If you are using that, go ahead and replace the step that talks of session attributes. If you are not using container managed authentication, and have rolled your scheme, then those methods will return null.

Comment: On the topic of getServletPath(), it will fail in certain scenarios. I don't remember which (possibly directories, as you alluded to). That's why I proposed separating the content.

Comment: @BalusC, no it doesn't. getRemoteUser() invokes getUserPrincipal().getName() or the equivalent. The IP is returned only for getRemoteAddr().

Answer (score 1):

Put the restricted pages in a specific folder, e.g. `/secured`, `/app`, `/private`, `/admin`, etc and map the filter (or the container managed security constraint) on an URL pattern which covers exactly that folder, e.g. `/secured/*`, `/app/*`, `/private/*`, `/admin/*` etc. Finally just put the login page outside that folder.

In [our servlet filter wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) you can find a code example which covers exactly this case.

Comment: Damn, that's a huge page for a tag.